# Can I create object with implicit parameter in java, as in c++?

Tags: java, c++, string, constructor, implicit-conversion

I can create String in java by implicitly assigning char array

```
String s = "asd";
```

instead of

```
String s = new String("asd");
```

This behaviour is similar to c++ with implicit one argument constructor.

So why cannot it make with another user-defined class?

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = 9;
    }
}
```

gives

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Foo
```

So why some "superior" classes from java API can have this contruct-implicilty-from-assignment behaviour, but custom, user define classes cannot?

Comment: fwiw, what happens in this line is radically different from what happens in a line with similar syntax in C++. They look similar, but thats due to similar syntax, otherwise C++ and Java are very different

Comment: @OP -- C++ is not Java, Java is not C++.  They are two different languages.

Comment: this is not argument. The question is not "Are Java and c++ the same language?" No. Read the question one again please.

Comment: You tagged C++ and Java.  That alone, without reading the question, is worthy of simply stating that C++ is not Java.  If you don't want C++ involved, don't tag C++, just ask about Java.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But reading the question makes it clear that the OP is not confused by that in any way. So while your statement is true, I'm not sure what purpose it serves. There's nothing wrong with referring to similarities between languages.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "That alone is worthy of stating c++ is not Java"... ??? So as someone is asking about the differencies about these two or similarities... it is forbidden?? What argument is this please???

Comment: The issue is that C++ is **not** Java.  If you have an issue or question about Java, then tag Java alone.  Just because C++ looks like Java doesn't mean you have to implicitly bring C++ into questioning why Java behaves a certain way.  If that's the case, then why not also bring in Algol, Fortran, Basic, Pascal, and other languages that look like Java.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so in other words. Mixing c++ tag with Java is forbidden according to you. So please tell the stackoverflow maintainers to forbid to mix these two tags. Not to me. Very thanks

Comment: your question is not about similarities, but your question has a false premise when you say "This behaviour is similar to c++ ..." you can remove that false premise without altering the question substantially, then you can also remove the C++ tag. Your faulty assumption that they are similar aside, none of this is actually related to C++ ;)

Comment: All you have to do is remove the C++ tag, and just state "In Java I can do this with `String`, but can't do it with other classes.. Why?".  and be done with it.

Comment: note that even if you know that "This is similar in c++ ..." is sloppy and not strictly speaking correct it might confuse others. Please don't feed that misunderstanding

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And if you were asking the question, you could do that. It's unclear to me why you're insisting that the OP do it.

Comment: and if you are not aware that it is not quite correct, then better we told you ;)

Comment: *I can create String in java by implicitly assigning char array*: the statement is wrong. The literal `"asd"` is an `Object`. In Java this is not an array of `char` under any circumstance. From [class String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): *All string literals in Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class*

Answer (score 4):

There are no implicit constructors in Java. A series of characters surround by double quotes is a [string literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). As you suspected, this definition is part of the language itself, and there is no way to create literals for your own types in Java.

Comment: String s = "asd" is implicit conversion, you can say whatever you want. Or otherwise, where is constructor for that String object?? Where is the argument specified for the String constructor function? The argument is on the side of assignment, that is exactly what "implicit" means

Comment: No, it is most definitely not.  The right hand side is a string literal, as specified in the language definition.  Note that as a full-fledged String object, you can do things like `"asd".startsWith("a")`

Comment: Importantly, `String` and support for it is uniquely built into the language, in a way that isn't available for any other types.

Comment: @LouisWasserman right, so you just confirm what I said. They are java API classes that are **superior** to user-defined classes. Because they dispose of functionality that a "ordinary" user cannot ever achieve. Is that what Java makes that magnificent?

Comment: That makes a value judgement I don't think is appropriate.  It's just a design choice made by the language, which has some pros and some cons.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I do not think that supporting implicit constructors would make java ever harder to maintain :), still trying to figure out the background of this choice. Maybe the main purpose was to distinguish from c++?

Comment: It makes the language more explicit about what's happening everywhere.  It makes it consistent whether or not the newly constructed object is being assigned to a variable or passed directly to a function.  When reading Java code, a new object is created on the heap if and only if the keyword `new` is present.

Comment: @LouisWasserman unless it is superior String, then it could be created from assignment (implicit) expression

Comment: Not even then, exactly, because of the way strings are treated as constants.

Comment: String is a basic datatype in the language.  There exist denotations for Strings `"foobar"` just as there exist denotations for other datatypes such as ints `42` and floats `42.0`.  That String is a class type does not seem relevant.  The OP's argument seems to hinge in the belief that `"foobar"` is **not** itself a String and therefore needs to be "converted" into a String.

Answer (score 3):

First, you are mistaken: `"asd"` is not a *char array*, it is a *string literal*, and it is certainly not the same as `new String("asd")`.

Unlike some other programming languages, Java is very static and does not support extending the language itself, e.g. features like *operator overloading* and *implicit construction* are not supported.

The Java language has a set of built-in data types documented in [Chapter 4. Types, Values, and Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html): `String` and all the [primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) (`boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float`, and `double`). Conversions between those types are covered by [Chapter 5. Conversions and Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html).

Some Java types, mostly the ones in the [`java.lang`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) package, are part of the Java *Language*. They have very special meaning, are explicitly documented in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), and are not considered "superior", but simply "native" to the language. Here are some examples:

- [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a native Java class: [§4.3.3. The Class String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3), [§3.10.5. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), [§5.1.11. String Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), [§5.4. String Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4), and [§15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator `+`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).
- [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). and [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)  are native Java classes and have an entire chapter dedicated to them: [Chapter 11. Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).
- Many annotations, such as [`Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) and [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), have special meaning to the Java language: [§9.6.4. Predefined Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4).
- [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) is a native Java interface with special meaning to the try-with-resources statement: [§14.20.3. try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3).
- [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) are native Java interfaces with special meaning to the `for` loop: [§14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).